# SAS : Map a column from 1 table to any of the multiple columns in another table

Tags: sas

I have a table1 that contains 4 different kind of ids

```
Data table1;
Input id1 $ id2 $ id3 $ final_id $;
Datalines;
1 a a1 p
2 b b2 q
- c c2 r
3 d - s
4 - d4 t
```

A table2 contains any of the ids from id1, id2 or id3 of table1:

```
Data table1;
Input id $ col1 $ col2 $;
Datalines;
1 gsh ywu
b hsjs kall
c2 jsjs ywe
3 sja weei
d4 ase uwh
```

I want to left join table1 on table2 such that I get a new column in table2 giving me final_id from table1.

How do i go about this problem?

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Can there be multiple changes? Will `a1` be in the record more than once? If so, this becomes a recursive lookup which is vastly different.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using SQL:

```
proc SQL noprint;
create table merged as
    select b.final_id, a.*
    from table2 as a left join table1 as b
    on (a.id eq b.id1 or a.id eq b.id2 or a.id eq b.id3)
;
quit;
```